# Comparar un rango de horas y minutos en JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un sistema de control de personal, haciendo uso de un lector de huellas digital.

Estoy en la etapa de validación. Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer la validacion entre la hora obtenida y la hora que tiene el usuario establecida en la base de datos, teniendo una rango de minutos de aceptación?

Hasta ahorita esto es lo que tengo para hacer la validación.

```
public void validarHora(ArrayList<Horario> horas) {
    try {
        Date now = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        //obtenemos la hora de chequeo
        String s = df.format(now);
        //Realizamos la validacion
        Date comparar1, comparar2,comparar3;
        //hora actual
        comparar1 = df.parse(s);
        for (Horario hora : horas) {
            //hora1
            comparar2 = df.parse(hora.getHoraEntrada());
            System.err.println(comparar1.compareTo(comparar2));
            //hora2
            comparar3 = df.parse(hora.getHoraSalida());
            System.err.println(comparar1.compareTo(comparar3));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Un ejemplo sencilo que puedo dar.

Voy y checo a las **6:54 am** que es a la hora que ingreso, y en la BD mi hora de entrada esta a las **7:00 am** con un rango de aceptacion de **10mins** lo cual entre a la hora dentro del rango y viceversa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `compareTo()` se utiliza para comparar objetos o en el caso de tipos `String` para determinar la cadena más "grande"; no es lo que necesitas para tu problema en particular.

Para comparar 2 fechas existen librearías como [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (versiones de Java 7 o inferior), entiendo que Java 8 posee una mejor implementación para trabajar con tipos de dato `Date`.

En concreto tu caso lo podrías trabajar de una manera sencilla y sin recurrir a librerías externas, te propongo lo siguiente:

```
public static boolean evaluarLimite(Date date1, Date date2) {
    boolean correcto = false;
    long diferencia = (Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())) / 1000;
    long limit = (60 * 1000) / 1000L;//limite de tiempo

    if (diferencia <= limit) {
        correcto= true;
    }
    return correcto;
}
```

Indicas que puedes basarte en un tiempo limite (60 segundos en mi ejemplo) si la diferencia de tiempo entre ambas fechas es mayor a tu limite, entonces deberás tomar la decisión o ejecutar el evento que se requiera.

Ajusta el metodo para que mida la unidad que deseas, toma en cuenta que lo que te muestro arriba trabaja en base a segundos (milisecs/1000) = secs.

Comment: He probado la respuesta que me dijiste, y se acomoda perfectamente a mis necesidades en la comparacion de rangos, gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con `Para comparar 2 fechas existen librearías[sic]`? Las fechas se pueden comparar directamtente en Java (con `compareTo` o con `after` y `before`; sin necesidad de librerías. Es cierto que se pueden usar librerías para añadir otro tipo de operaciones, pero la comparación está en el java base. Y `Date` existe desde Java 1.